# I could not generate either Enterprise or Partner WDSL

Tags: apex, community

I have created an account in Salesforce but I could not generate either enterprise or partner WSDL. When I try, they ask me to login again and the system could not proceed to the next step.

For sure, I want to integrate my client's developed software to his existing software connected to Salesforce database.

Here is a sample of codes:

```
<?php
define("CLIENT_ID", "donatien.info@gmail.com");
define("CLIENT_SECRET", "....");
define("REDIRECT_URI", "https://localhost/resttest/oauth_callback.php");
define("LOGIN_URI", "https://login.salesforce.com");
?>
```

> Result:error=invalid_client_id&error_description=client%20identifier%20invalid

I hope someone is ready to help me fix this issue.

Comment: how you downloaded the WSDL from Setup -> API  -> WSDL?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be an OAuth issue, not a WSDL issue. You can generate WSDLs by logging into the Salesforce application with your own credentials.

`CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET` are not a username and password, which appears to be what you're providing since you have an email address recorded for `CLIENT_ID`. These the values established when you create a Connected App in Salesforce, under which umbrella you authenticate via OAuth. Depending on which OAuth flow you're using, you may also be providing a username and password.

There's more information that may be useful in the [Understanding Authentication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_authentication.htm) portion of the REST API Developer Guide.

Note that you need to [Create a Connected App](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=connected_app_create.htm&type=5) in Salesforce if you have not done so already, and record your Consumer Key and Consumer Secret values for use in implementing the OAuth flow you've chosen.